# Draw.io - How do I make a button that toggles layers in the light box

Tags: app.diagrams.net

When using draw.io can i create a link that will allow a button to switch a layer on and off without actually clicking on the layers area?

In the below picture I want the user to be able to click on the "Switch on or toggle layer 1" to make the "yellow" layer 1 box appear and disappear.

[image]

The lightbox in the image can also be opened [here](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=Untitled%20Diagram.xml#R7XxXl6PIsu6vmcd7Ft48ghDCCCNhxRteeI%2BAX38zVdU9bcadu2efOWvdXatbJYIkyYz44ouIJKlf8FOzXcawf2pdkta%2FYEiy%2FYILv2AYijIU%2BAUl%2B4eEYrAPQT4WyWejXwVWcaSfQuRTuhRJOn3XcO66ei7674Vx17ZpPH8nC8exe33fLOvq7%2B%2Fah3n6k8CKw%2FpnqVck8%2FNDymD0r3IpLfLnlzujFPtxJgrjKh%2B7pf283y8Ynr1%2FPk434Ze%2BPic6PcOke30jws%2B%2F4Kex6%2BaPb812Smuo2y9q%2B7hO%2FJ2zn%2BNew3r5nMk13NPx63TGtJ3%2FSj%2FYb%2FcDRJ9dTfP%2BRVfv2abwQvQXnH89izm1%2BjCGZ18AHUD2nJv68%2FTX%2BSLgIO6aIv48UYdRWvNftXfq6m4Ep9quTeFl89hV6RchUGpCRRRJfT3zxUiwp6yo629aAt1jcQzlXTuLYVPUEJNuOiZhG36KPwGIYp%2FH31yOvH%2BAPKyLvAWyGKgQaALnP1WUjnO6%2FYCaX9WMfrUp8JW0a9J53EGTLxfgnzD4dBOU%2BDx%2B%2FQo69AtUnt8AjvqUhZ84z792%2FatRwZdPu%2F62jcnftTH234UL%2Fmdd%2FdNwoWImjbK%2FApckTJnsH4ML%2BYdwwf9JuFC%2Fa2P8vwsX4s%2B6%2Bk24IP9zcGEpGg%2F%2FErukaEKm9D8FF%2BoP4UJi%2FyBc6J9sbL2KOX4CWdfCj%2FEd0%2FMcGBpD6v9d0YVlKZQh%2F5L9qQRJYB%2F5GCZF%2Bp1xE5LG2eR%2FJzZ%2BjDwY%2BT%2BIDZT4ycxpAvKvz8NPq3zv%2Bd9YOQmn51dETHM4zhxM%2Bb61J5CJBbz%2F%2B9r38RdNg%2BO0TX64Aki%2BaQ%2BOPltDDJTpPO%2Bfx%2BEyd0DUjfOzy7s2rK9d138dyQ8o%2BmrA71GE%2FYwiUTydRPEvIQWj%2FwApH2qFuvxjWADVd8sYf7ZifhspY1qHc7F%2B39Vvmf3zUrMrwE1%2BDVbkDwhjkP9CaYakUQJ7fxLf9whslKfzZyc%2FYOnrqP4avMh%2FCV7pVsz%2BFySA7w%2F4%2Fb%2FINy7AGPyvIAIHv577Dyj%2FDaAEEeKNim9Cyr%2BA079KT8xPoUsCZoHRClacYxrOMGSFkBj3Ph3roq1%2BgVRJ1WCgfATiGJXDb%2FMzhP5QwKtCGPOWKX0Xo19DX9HmoHHYwDDWRlP%2FVVvfQBfEtP4DtnP65xHw1%2FrTWGbQ%2Fxd0%2FU0hqE6z%2BQ9R9XPxBWvfvyVk4egPhILT%2F0X%2BHLSY3whaDPk3BC3qJ9P8P7HKB5N84ZVvWeUbknn8PUQS1V1c%2Ff%2FOJOw%2FxyTsT0zyu%2B5dNO8lKR66SBEDzcOM1eymYi466HlRN89d8%2Fup7LfO9qUP7tNrZ2hEPpz6j6WyrNggQvn3LbkvUuSLBHxPwhnYhfs4xMQe0tSpcHnj%2FkLUS95x4Ee3nOfZycG3Ah4L%2BYmTwe9Tsc5dBhtwvm7dEZkbJyKmblBwb28OyoM2W%2FlamcfNgUIlPj%2BD%2BMVx5xY04hWES8hGwkHH%2FGFazp13pWdKJ4ge81ubxcmmxa9Xz232eeDqMxXYRlH12%2Fn00HWtf2jD46ndFVXl88ZUCm53EMXyy3OvW5baSuBza4PYUk9nJUgU53VrekDePEds8liyTGH4mEN71wgYXyyohG6tPZFiynqXJyKLslEDfuNJw6I9i9v4E88OajOPgzYncGKd2v5oayyuPd87xCWb%2ByFt3bh%2B3ocEk8wdOU0PNL2DpmOPOq9xamkP2I6f81bU8SmjwrungdAiykCIwqGNjNAsp%2BeSFE%2B237HbHs%2FkIQ61Y%2FVOjJQDTKb5U%2Bvap2XP5odJYafYwQHLArv14mMbmZL2bGrOfcXEJ58MnwG79SDoKJe8irojdrJz6SYyZpZEWjKJNFHX%2B3DqyE26DxsjmgPGAxLBxHTL6k4kyIEpwZFvq8%2FSJyVsatGIX07R%2BgBSAP22MdX9XnzpHUkVaapKz0zklykcMcauEX%2FjuU7qqbQLL8%2Fi3pVagnvrVvXPq%2B0wNRK2L0SfrzaC482h1Pa1Hh20v0ZPycFnsmJnR1FQ4AheRQ8euGt43powRtvIiGSsbhgx7I7wmNjuJqzYcc4EesTRC5voQ4ZVyDASD3IUvW0GgV4ksfApdKmddslUAuBj9C2hEw8FZub1hG33jEHYwmSjKgtkUowOR66bJVyIUU0Hw9VBswHa6lycrPsoixV3cZliKBefOrMme%2FILPJB4diKxJWts%2B6Vx59NTAe2EzVM33zy0oL%2B2%2FWa2TmOUSHhZxpxWfNBj05pkLHAnjgvWQ6aWLF58cyDu68a9uE4FLWSJ47kTkcfcmbsW%2FIu7ccvvyzScJiZX416a%2FMyAe8m2UD6JZOXkk3gDmoAuqHDgC3BKa4124ka6e3v10hOcJPDaugpvmz76q1tqLbyDIygjXpfXzfpoIRyPMDLMqyKdBYbLpSZMQHcPGbbVeLZhp9eaP%2FKMO4MLVXDhPTNLhe10pVf7MASuYwSCeQZzLuXGzoymbACM%2BfzM1doe6Ce3Lnf%2BfSfuKUsEGNI5f8%2FE%2BmOpZhiSTz90TsyJjWMAT92hF8s2zahoHwW4MHUBj3pdGIlPb8bDbHZ5LkJ01vdRYWR7e9YG1PZG6Z4Y4bJ2rXTRTpw25PlylVSEcGrWuh%2FqMyKY3HlTRwBjA5gJt1zAILQKaJzPX%2B4d%2BLpoHFezryOEFHDmgr%2BKrJ%2BqA%2BNXOFzwj3o4l42%2BkBCAZ2q4ythTMFOgXSBwRYEhRbEPuMqSsX1iLF31TPxBTKmnG2E%2Fn0f%2F8TpzeTgi6INlGU%2FEmA3iPBjW2TXdEe1llrty3FCA3JQ%2F1PIlHTCMzYwQ2Kjr%2ByA2ihr9uHFA7XeTDmzKAZLqVBMawGIXrPsZXIgZ7dNLmKs17HY24rJR1tMUmlogBABxt5UbVIlIJs7IlV4SGZJcoR6uFLEq7F2%2FMZvl3FzpYKk%2BEIfMiCNOsYSLDe70NNuXwJnQ8LL%2F1208aBKRZvSD5k0a08sH%2BL%2FrZJWqRByYh7%2FvdFQfGU7lLDZm7SC%2FW1joCvkDgNxwKkfFxZKx6FVzTO4lTOxCA%2FjyxJSoQVWpxC0wSZ9gVAydfd8fayxKXPXmJ%2B6t4SE%2Fhk%2BG6xQ9aNci8Hb1Xl23PmzGgTZeMeLUfDK4VlPfWp25mdw1L7Ju2B9MasD%2F9ztWOX3vKEd2Fl4nQm7pBp2v1tSa7dGSyQOwM98jDvjoq5waBkKrs4pg2CdGs8lycUM2F65gtIi5gs9Ya0KMnOwSpDPxBhJisbv610qf0vs9OsWADtR7dmhRvHjXGNePO5JIFriOYTQZv17uvjq4ijEUi9C2G4M%2BsdczCaX8RmUxk5hYlIanw%2F%2FgjJMyMiNdDUHqu2eBPTD6uT3QOWp2W19af3TNaxeI8dA7FTWohCGtUuku%2BrXILiV7JEPBA6YI1EoLn%2By8jUWAkXWxMfN5hlGwB1gTc2QtiQer8NdHgax1Q6oueT25PlpNq%2BNjI0NeOnWDKF20fEBGCGzMdsiCFfjlrhR%2BGNXZJV22DTdxku2k2wm9h6HZllbvwlwOUDgoz0TXvuZTZJITFq33D1%2B0bpmLxmc6a6%2BjgGOFS%2BGepp9acHVaPVkqQuKi5mHkq0szuk%2F7Ji27lYzBiE79RaDwylQRLB1DygHz1J2gtvtwOMLBAJ0LjX85g9CCUFqS0zgYAt%2FekCWrbmAUnWNIl%2BcUKV6j8YoilsdpvyOFnYh8IjmD0tLbJT8eLPXCLflIdHBbPaT8WhYQLjIOEN%2FiS6gnlUW9mLlZjbKxaNvArFIUJ8JNc4EQwo68SpWNFY9Fay8d1jhDC4JyrSm14TfBKNuqb1VMe%2FfOR9hryWmrmL0BLHFYy7perlUZuCAL0RFHRJLV0CVl8ePXkUVAHSoj5lMVmASgE95o0rqPHyFnhqgFeOHsK0xdGlKkGb1kIScGkrxELqRzbKsbmLJs3HjX2l2zHkZ96FUpoo3D6RV2cHGY7vAim%2FmIpRHAhyF%2BPYRS42Jxz4NNLfZFw4lJT8LeVycspYc1W6%2BAjNNan8VI3mMc5PD8ugXtY7kIbJC2Gb2lsd7jIXJOcKPmIV%2B2g8YP3HmIKZD48eHBPjeCmV6e3eWv2LRmckLP3%2Fj0Rm8daOfxxm2OeoAW%2BvKaRHkvr2bzbON%2B5udsiF%2BgyU4r9bOE6Zk7lMPHZTPSKqxSL8kCTHbDA%2Bhad5s66xGhJjfppqG30DOVC%2B2ugwXxavW8pizOSS67PhW2QwMyXywJBBUum70EBNBs419BOEOhO4iAfw296qFj1LVU60aABY9I09YutJvAQq6PcW72x9FEaXBjs%2FmgOTWv0eG2kbpzM2HkqYuAyUOQyR6bzA0n%2BmzjlSjC2BGmxYV2riePC7nhDDm8FlN7gFMEPKs6Zn7qJXCg3P0KRnfBq4xFkczp0A7Vtik3f4A7iFn53KC7w4ojW%2Bps4jnx6YLc55HNNcbGkckwSQMdltiVhtku2xRd0DVNlswmMcsaeWFhLE1nhnMo0YSS%2BlqNzy3k%2BQczRiApJZ9bx5xtC2XoG8heeE%2BWXiAxkmFGwslhCT1eeDJv1xf5G4cKVkCBOselncFoydBDZ5xOBtSzYhFzHb1dbnaHdJyj6sNDVUfEfCoKr1o6gup2gCWtpf2Ky%2FrGMTcjJ59wjmSklBtBwv%2BiFN4BhqyW68A4BG8NFl0yO5t4UDGIAMg7CNHTFTmFvWwO1BRtngdyXzJpo0Af1D5tdN8dYT4YSMVLctp6UNvXSLkQbViktxau71M2ghL2uCs867ultzKAxnJGbqmlcfQc69ZUkVlvut3Nl6D2TVTet7G6obmJH8GC66WHDpG1VZePMTQR5C%2BlnaOwWAdYD3euv%2FBInYQ7Gy6%2BEzEgh9OJybvOGYvOWYn0B8Q59twG1ScG6gKrpRMEP4Tzvplkq1zlVSfxpLt41jDvNjXuuLPUIqnbSc%2FlL%2FwsEJxlZtHjgQ2n3e4pVn0O8Tsj3JvrQU54KoCKm69yWDYNwUQTyJ0yLk5dHtZljiSQfg8QyycbU9hz50LUNU8yO4uKAaAgbXE8VfV9Pcm1NftD3eHbmQ0koUeG62VzQk%2F%2FVoPY9QmxaKXRxR01UlXEfe%2FYbLTWi9Je5Sv2DsTcDWi0gRHCH9D4MSXpRRSZERmwMQHxsq6cVxP4%2BLEXyzpogGLPnxGenEj3YDGvth6tKZZ9R2%2FCzfWwfFQ8nu6vZ%2B3dc0dBMjvIp0mPb2WKWe26nCna11UmK6W4Px3yiHEjsvNhV0nf6oXOdc5XhoKNr7sdkiNOToynB3CQIC%2FJBQ2mDNd6h30TRD6gzlZuzg6K7XN4AXHz1Rm2fgf5yEdkr1F1ECAvX6ExeTrw3BlDGKUsAW%2BKo1oA5QrHJK043aRp6kSzeI6YWoxBNLldC1DAEyauHaCEparMPD1MUC%2B6bLdhBUC1aCURS%2Fe39cWpEORhCatn8myoZpt1Dn1JRK1q5id3yh%2FzHWQxomjfVnzMqw8%2FNovWQ0kTuwk34eRE5ia%2F8F3OLAmGKc1%2BXTKR6U96f4OJ5Km%2BX4EmYNA6QXVkA%2FgoQRU1XN4dF9lz7l%2F8IEFdzyJIiCEZ%2F5WaRHyVJKsppcaaAQqqnetdhVzIFfHFBlk8L%2BPnsrPMcPuopGoyoqnKfhcRr1OefXIUzJZuXPEdb30n04%2FyfpAODUKcGPE575glrM2iKzstu2Fdnota3ih9NoOLPd7RNXkXKmCY%2BXJLTarZ7icZk55MKqXHHGHsHB5tAHXPcUr1dteZSGZHa5FFC6q42fKgaO9YcgWxE9Z8J1AzvE7cmbfklrGr5VE7WklsWlnGWELyX%2B7lJNAPzffcpM95nCbb3AyLjFNZogG1b3UfeTCurXaM3TDyEjkgc3%2BZyNIbAzsvsdHbMGdNV0vNCNw9TiEuH2kdDYx2mgLTg5E1O4GbwNs2psZTpoItMi7TcX3tWGgfEpddf53juspSnBocyP2aaSo8Q2fpFS5oeAtaL3eMVH2XDlyuy%2BprH%2FvNcSCPy5PIM1KByNBSqJpt6wqdcpeDkGjf43k%2FWZVqT6OGBCVzv0BHHanZo9OhTRXCV6ZJpC3SIxcCYs3uly1S49oc2GnkYDASo5LE0gtwRr4%2B9ofdYXEJgojJdA7UXuAKjqinc1hCqL%2FwAVvG8U0HA9U%2FFj8bh4GCWTEMAmw6ujhrzF5kNruVZv41AMnRnLLH2E%2FSJ3O0Lne298V%2BLBmMHX5xPJ9RFFiKhFoeoqZtnD%2BHfZi82ocAu7k4cCKepXGzanzDdhBdzYVi4bfIH5kLr%2BN09Fps83hII3GHbMtBL1vvjlCBgSdeUS0MPgBqnhpLsZ5P06ODybnFzis1w0ANoXkzur98JOPROPh%2BZShtaRb8wp7aHpflcBpGcfFonIUzhcUr3nBEDPOINB5x8JtaO3oxhKEMnfy%2BR3FqSlBcXmCs6M5TZMM4hdqAlq8FBghCC30DX%2FXgbDwOwgjm93ocTGYosahgofDkzR4azMEcNdCGUV48An9p7fOjHeUd07KYBAmVH5J6BgrCPXFKWNGe4wYZ3WG7Ma56DkiWdZ8ICCLsCI18bdehiuje7z2UNlEnDODCklg3WYa4WnVqMhWkfwJuHM89AQGU314Z1BHiGbMM58RgFkpinj75aEH7QOAsdiH4c1Pe5UKH01g381rXGO0kfub7AQOTW5YcB9M%2FeZF4ueNUqo74esEKAqYPAxrOTpfpG7DHtIqlrb9QphqZ7qo6uoC6BXJq1tNYQLWT5iyjDNERbOpUJQbTv2Q2%2FHLAH6sX%2BfSVpmGNycX4cO6Di9oKxVOQ4TLH1bJgSu76Ys2Q4fX8SlhtfqKyNDMN7%2BtXqZm1GRKj9apZmB42dJ%2Bspq5Tq0AuyhbZir3jG%2Fui8d5rO13G6Uu11IT8lFyCSiEByqLOuMYbfqw9o1SQpLPthx2miXhIJdns4FN98my1YRY%2BAZkzLKNJ19jWynaf%2BEsvlZ5m75dXh%2FCTBEHgBAUMeWw6JZ4mXXQa3ZIskxT6vXATYR9YYOs9qSrkahfx%2BSPXYdUrslqmsG3efXs8K5i6i%2Bu1sVSaZSk5tSG0YhTPllJj2HUCtSCjiOyK4mQZtx5Hsw8Gw8H813n%2BMn%2FgbbsK%2BBqf9YZQ2gfZQiIrG7y1DQVLmhTdDrgsNQY3okjvkC%2FEjrHNB5YEBqSv0%2FBeRObsnrUiHFcbCaUzCl95ZebeSfk90%2BnVv8FZTa%2FQjEC22NNzmcEAaxoU5k7lbu0ryw6p%2BRoeOTXl5bGO4REwTGr6PfKhDpp9MaagsygCKctWJweesPE4zlJ69I8yZYC1REj7QovSihG57QtD%2FahybBRCZCBjyOrX6%2FXF6EJY2WIabBHIN%2F0r%2B2S6gFZgEgOXTwMLH%2Bb2IwfQo1OWHFc4VZswUimAOr7vhXm26WO1M%2BN6LpIkTQmcyMMGJN6taDb4ksRIlFlX75KKVa%2FlFwp6kI%2BlwQhcJ9Wb2WmpQZcOTEvS0TvM8i6M9f46RtTPb74l0GvCNAOehI8qxcm%2Bp1zzaEJ3byOid2iYf7ABc7g4LULMsITYsrg1EgcOEct2hgQSLekuU6fwjK%2FGWYcMSqdj3DajjdGX3py3%2FY4uZcZmRgnVS0onTG6a%2FKbTFZNCRvBxNrkncaxdAg2LiyouMTqZsjS17vzGMrHEvxwFv0O%2BZc18UxaaXJfuXnVFcrxCxV3ZrkQOlcTnAtJB37HtcQhDk0UVbR5DZLIbfBog1TNFztI0%2BaqDRCwJiYt%2BjH5T1qZKaSB%2FhUOX7PQks0YpeVk4kH1kCCisdKdVTbnbegvQBYKUHd0Hsqw6o3PXrb6Px3whUVfFGjQACeU65XcnNfGIKoN1vZ2ojDYvNiR%2F4vyCtM%2FqPfLIzFk%2F0Okgh359P7Hpi5HunzP7UFEMN3B28xWsnsw68VA281kCFnwwAt5ukPZYikR8E4cKFJhNtLGj3dYy7Rk82T4QRX0QEWRUx4R22V9GxfmlE9LLa730WoruzgaH9QgdbA7aE%2BU5Lgj5LXu1lOCxUauvYo5t1oqFzsHlfNxCNt9APl1bzYY9XcYzes9j6HIbuk1SHsxdywzJI9bHIkVMjpMQy9XQCEwoXY%2B4ptTmnPRGcGdjNbMVLL9GSbg81%2Bc2trSmB3sBIJdSU0Jg1FZDdgvwlZQ3iX6SzeEa1%2Fq95qUJb%2F7pygccO8XcxTELRV1eesdF9mTM4QJ2S6zGMZEzgNKViIu7TGdJMi%2BtuV42yAjjCa40UDRBPlqaRm29aGC5J13ZngwYyziCiYmJ%2FpynKBUVAY7uK8yzg1ksMleoKipVUrSdVaGvJcuv6XsHsgBvC62pJq%2BC5zlOT%2FtBSUw2yyAoNDp8AoNJDQlSVpCTYbxD8ultZExeF7YnTT1vmUmHIVWXrCgX2Xo5LYhZkrjSs2ixg7x8BpkWZWQSLrz85MPCuTuuWYYRamRT7Q0yt8nGqw4ruWlRRx%2Bt0W1DB1C4MnQLseBhybbvGM6aGT7QgZWKe%2FTG%2FVghc03MQXrePZ%2BNrJfV3k0rw0rcH6tIz6hAAxC%2F3FLkQet17T8oI2Y0W6MN1piSgCSn8D7Gyl0ooFspyeXFaPHVz5ZTsQPOft0fj3QguzCwouzqMuozh8ps2eMMte42mui1mVQmiwlLUuECU8Qop6Gd24QmYRrkZBOmtzodtBlEFg%2BYVtuwPU2y99OLw8%2FhHhcR1ze1H2RQI%2FgAQaJhtQeNwACmP7F6hW3rQGlh1XKz0ktR7FTYnMr5iZ11aU6aDTQV0XC5en41DRTLItpVd9Fg4h%2BIZRTFlSXctXFC3d13qTdChA2XJd0HEi0lfaiD8cFe93XbCwmuMvFlum5nAi4R8yC%2FfPqkaOf8zLq1t6u7yLqzM0a9e8JLDdFw6mzW0BYo1%2BXJ8UB7NIEK4C1KtyHdqksQQWxfC%2BUgMCYKKGxL%2BWKG2vHKgs%2FXPsYlmqYBWYBRptl6pvHVbnRkrXwJR9GUBXnwtMIsf99DiiLv7YM2jtld0Xeun5pEU1N7UNF95J%2Bn2fYa4TzLr416svcTiQAX9%2BCs2FAAbgVtY0rcNVtmflPkInRhmcFvPolvd%2FuFKjKdblaR2yaVT4qD8KildqrFdvf1da7LAT6%2BTPCVGSezMdutrti5fvbB3ueo4iHZ0mBS7FAtJzCglgngivkKpgMJL8uyRMGLLVvb495V%2FprGoPw%2BnejIQ%2Beh1npTJfWSZJQoG72ZElTslizoOiDecyFZO1O9deum4J75WEe2ZhGUMmHMyjHQb%2FhWsKR31JAbeKGs%2BXDYiSEZQcVXX2F2GJ39a5UYt8PE8j1B1lB8XyWoidkeUQFZD4dAg8xb1yibrmt5VxaS3vp0udCskb6wphWRi5cuB8g8PBzNL0VAl%2Bzak3VsyC1Zng%2B8YCj0fmgw3NC3iCbt29m9rlw%2FMlcIBpBqMY9KaksSYuY6XRZykpqJPV9rAmtf%2Fg2OgMxe7gVWz%2B6u2cUdlwTimWZmMLL4Tucsw%2BiKKFGQAN4fcrQYT4IUNzRMCGlOG%2FhYjic0H%2FePyyQzgWGUDns5EEIrkYDi0ZKVNYbpO0F9L5E5cOWzOq1wfOkrKyifRBBuaOUjWyKcUKl5uhzFPaG2J8NCTgx36KOjzFMf5RMTjiOMVCCnhWErvMMVOfxWU35mVJGLA3UBgPbNwmS29RSK4rTRbs%2F4poml62K483UEtadaLT2C6u7pMqrDFroZfOrE%2B%2BLMyEXbP5oXtJBgMi8UZVu6JI2DITF4w7wCkXo0xztUxsOwKD%2ForDmNOIX0xQnLpmCgbA%2BSidwYNkFWIHN3PzJ3Stdt43bbSde7WyOddSo5W3SKsYo0B3CtBroLO185bMYFCo8AmFofuakTSBB2%2B3xkVahm%2BdjGHrI7zMxkCZ4wbk%2FBGFI4YTm49yFtO6piqtu7SrV%2BrlJfl4k2BHtLjJRQZLwqb7YJCe8VgvQe3umoRzGbYXhYL0H%2BuKZ%2Bmx07SM7yvo6zIUB2s8XpgsfrU0vSqhwDtO29w6zIJWuwkmBqP2Vig%2B0YfJ5ifH5sC70dEX7o8BGlPEr7YoazWZAGTs94aIYUir8TUs9%2FEUVWRYZ9fjSZp96lElK4vXHsfoOBOAWE%2BYLFtHgC5mLdpUGp7HwMkNHjOQPl7vrSzjb7QpIxbNbEPKEx%2FWXNQ5iP9TaM6bt4fFHzuQ4x08drh27Y3cAVi1ptBa5tCUQDfF5eMno2GRzuI5jgAj0psCe4iDPb0LSw08ih7fq1vpY%2BhVF%2FXhy9b8KtXlzu%2BLVPuVvNLqhn37xJ8wFdpbVHuJLGncezwNwhLYjE%2FcxKDNMYyROCnLudTm7xhIXxaBNUEBGhx67Rl90JvNy%2B1%2BdeBJNhOx3ZL8ywYQJ6UXKfZsPjY7WNyx8GvXWQC1sPYxmZH3t6kWn8xXGAb9%2BPbuhXZMNVZnA9pdmcRYHqxdTMAe63mEDaqm1WJvF7QvHviM3DEoqThVx87FnNw2zzBZ8Cq5z2sXpXxgSW7A6gJ30AafIrg3s8ZG%2BQiEviF%2F3Ofq7S7R1Qwe10zs2c52T76yoRagjd3vArmLV1%2F5wtA1AxvO%2B1xuBeJ%2F4Fn6VINKFvpk1crOBzpdE5fW48aAwYEZcnfGYn8q87xnysC%2FG3DlzdfeycsN8a4jk4KrgaSz2ngD6koid9MDLuDJcC4NgsuDLKnbmnxrHZRGOCDGO%2FILOYcKOQhE5Gxjesjza8VmgSu5itH%2Bo9TF7EAxrRaC%2FrfPEAieDAbmfxKDe2r2C%2F%2B6WX0Sq6K3BPxHt3S67h5ARX%2F8VKeJuRO%2BXZX90Z8ynDYa5TV9ps2ghVO%2Bpz0M8lA7o%2BBd%2Bs0N5hgdBJnMin9DBBCnBMBuhRff44c1n4xlY%2FSl8CrGdJzdSO84sCqYL4mH61UjZXGHPTOPUEYzKvnOESWCDgDIdwOccFILIBwRywhKnTEYavzcG3PQ8VcbrHadtTyqXcAaYo8J3JpI1IxdyyOFmFm%2FSs7KEJN1RBzmVMGooUCGqQCN0s3BV9KvP9rup311dlKrGMnGS9V5Q3NGayMzdedL%2FKKCpxNRWW2jwKzTU%2BlM1OaAliqHKZjfQt7S7D3i%2FXpiSqdN%2FNUj%2FR8qQNrqW67l6JmjynZv5X98A9xN1maYhFr%2FOyOEybHu4bUz3TAbVlJXbjg2irsArb5Hkwf22c5WXdzTkwIQlx5Jh3UWtBmzD986qcsjK5jNLL%2BeHuuV82426yiTZc9KzKwj1zpwuhLCwMa5EFPDqus1Z%2BwJ7u7Kj8sfae7bvwKXvClzV1QCb%2BiT9sYXk1QvyML8RpN7kYsLqkBclF3mnt8%2FxqSq%2FrI%2Fmt2fy8Ww%2F3sHRyTI7j6%2FdK%2FtddXrdKAMjlTzfz3yjloxikwfAEw9L%2BPL6ymxu894eea1DBWsutOZ3%2BppeavryI%2BrlDnEB%2BfqmJJImf94d%2FfSXxX9ogjvy82xcXf9rwC6Y3f781fEyn4gijdwO4C7eH78C8B0Lyv5AC3Lq7zN306w7vH3bj%2F%2FZ236kP46LN7fcG7v9D%2FM4269%2FZjf3n27zpv%2BkdReTHTf0%2Fm%2By3XkP7IvuXDPbz2%2FL%2FMdifGuyHtzDw3%2FCxf5vBfv6zBP8x2J%2B%2BNvPDW8AY9luvzfxNJoNB9uvfrnif%2B%2BYPhODn%2Fws%3D)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I really understand you but as far as I know, you can create a link on the object with the text "switch on or...." with the following text:

```
data:action/json,{"actions":[{"toggle":{"cells":["1"]}}]}
```

So whenever you click on the object, the layer will toggle visibility.